# MOSFET getting hot. Is it normal?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, led-driver, constant-current

I am using a [Diodes AL8871Q](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/AL8871Q#tab-details) IC to power a XHP70 LED at 3.4 A. My thermal cam shows the MOSFET at 108 degees C after 60 seconds with PWM control running at 40% duty. Is this expected?

MOSFET I am using is a [IRLB8743PbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlb8743pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356605d6b2593)

Using the [provided excel calculator sheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Calculators/AL8871Q-calculator.xls), I plugged in my values:
[image]

Calculator shows these outputs, so I am wondering if it's ok. My room ambient is about 26 degrees C
[image]

I get a recommended schematic 1 - Buck topology
[image]

Here's a WIP of how am planning to mount the driver
[image: Planned mounting]

Comment: You probably want some more heatsinking.

Comment: They predict that the MOSFET will dissipate around 3W.  Even if the FET dissipation is that low, it will need heatsinking to dissipate the heat.  Please *edit your question* to include a photograph of your board and the FET heatsink.  If you have data on the heatsink you're using, please include it.

Comment: Currently I am testing without a heat sink attached. I am making my own led headlamp and planned for the board to be bolted down with the FET directly clamped down to the aluminum housing, thus acting as a heatsink.

Comment: Added image of planned mounting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is expected that running this MOSFET without a heatsink will get surprisingly hot even with very little power dissipation. Note this section of the datasheet:

[image: thermal resistance]

notes are on page 9:
[image: note 5 note 6]

Dissipating 3W with a "typical" heatsink would give a typical temperature rise of \$  ( R_{\theta JC}\text{ of }1.11\text{}\frac{^{o}C}{Watt}  + R_{\theta CS}\text{ of }0.5\text{}\frac{^{o}C}{Watt} + R_{\theta SA}\text{heatsink to ambient} ) \times 3\text{}W = \text{approx }5^{o}C \$

Typical numbers are not guaranteed, but are a good general guideline. They didn't specify the heatsink but just any "flat greased surface".

However, dissipating 3W without any heatsink would give a Junction-to-Ambient temperature rise of \$  R_{\theta JA}\text{ of }62\text{}\frac{^{o}C}{Watt} \times 3\text{}W = 180^{o}C\$ (maximum). It might not get that high, but it will certainly get very hot. The Junction-to-Ambient thermal resistance is extremely high.

Unlike the typical "Case-to-Sink, Flat Greased Surface", the Junction-to-Ambient maximum rating does actually spell out the physical mounting in note 5: one square inch of printed circuit board (25.4mm x 25.4mm), and they do mean for most of that to be copper (which provides some amount of heat sink). This is a pretty good approximation of the heat sinking that happens in a circuit when there isn't a "heat sink" attached to the FET, instead the heat finds its way out of the very-hot junction by thermal conduction through the leads of the device, into the less-hot parts of the circuit. So there is some natural heat sinking that occurs, but at a very high thermal resistance, so it does get very hot with very little power dissipation.

Heatsinking is very important for FET, because unlike a BJT, FETs are subject to a harmful effect called *thermal runaway*: when a FET starts to overheat due to excessive drain current, its threshold voltage *decreases* -- which effectively drives the FET even harder, making it heat up more, making its threshold voltage decrease even more... Usually we either guard against the problem by overdesigning the heat sink to stay well away from thermal runaway.

[image: threshold voltage vs temperature]

Comment: Case to sink thermal resistance is not the total thermal resistance with a "typical" heat sink. It is just the thermal resistance between the case and an attached heat sink. I would expect a reasonable heat sink having a several times larger Rth.

Comment: @LarsHankeln whoops, you're right, I forgot to include Junction-to-Case...

Comment: Also heat-sink to ambient i believe.

Comment: Thanks for the very detail reply. Helped in understanding the datasheet a little better. Was wondering if I used a wrong mosfet for the job.

Comment: How can I tell/measure the transient time of the MOSFET? From what I've learnt so far, the longer it is, the hotter it gets? The calculator mentions that the resistor at the MOSFET gate should be tested and changed according, could this resistor be causing the gate to charge too slowly?